# Html.BeginForm() with an absolute URL?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I need to have the POST action be to an absolute URL (e.g., http://www.cnn.com).  Is there a way to use Html.BeginForm() helper and pass it the url?

Answer (score 76):

BeginForm method has several overloads.
In order to set the action attribute on the form tag with the desired url, you need to use following overload of BeginForm:

```
BeginForm(String, String, FormMethod, IDictionary<String, Object>)
// here are the parameter names:
BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, method, htmlAttributes)
```

Since you want to post to an external site, there is no need to set actionName and controllerName, just leave them as null.

```
@Html.BeginForm(
   null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@action="http://cnn.com/post"}
)
```

This will not encode the action parameter.

Answer (score 17):

All that the `HtmlHelper.BeginForm` method does is help you to create a `<form>` tag that targets a local controller.  If you're posting to an external site, just write out the actual `<form>` tag, i.e.

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/someaction" method="post">
    Actual form content in here
</form>
```

That's all there is to it.  MVC forms are not like the forms in ASP.NET WebForms where you have a bunch of ViewState and event fields and other magical elements.  They're just regular old HTML forms.

Comment: Yeh, I did this.  But I was just wondering if I was missing something in MVC (coming from RoR Land, there is a form {url=()} method.  Thx.

Comment: there may be some thins related to validation that don't get created for you if you manually create the form - so watch out if you're using the MVC validation with jQuery

Comment: As simon weaver pointed out, if you don't use the HtmlHelper validation framework does not work. I encountered this problem myself

Comment: And if you want the validation also, use @{ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext(); } where you use the begin form and @{ViewContext.FormContext = null; } wherever you should close the using of the beginform.

Comment: Simon_Weaver's and Zasz's comments are unbelievably useful for anyone considering following Aaronaught's advice.

Answer (score 0):

check the mvc source code, html.beginform method not only create the native html form only, but also add sth for client validation which just i want,

```
if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled) 
{
    htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = tagBuilder.Attributes["id"];
}
```

so it will be a problem, i just write my own extension