# Using Custom paths or absolute URI with Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Html.BeginForm() with an absolute URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965103/html-beginform-with-an-absolute-url)

How to put and absolute URI in the action attribute of the `<form>` tag generated by the `Html.BeginForm()` MVC3 Html helper. I am using MVC3 validation and do not want to lose it by writing my own Form tags.

I tried out both `Html.BeginForm(new { action ="http://absolute.com"})` and `Html.BeginForm(new { @action ="http://absolute.com"})` and the rendered html was `<form action="/Pro/Contact/http%3a/absolute.com/">`. As you can see it is being appended instead of replaced.

Comment: I think mine is more specific than the other, in that, I want the MVC validation framework to work, whereas "dale" does not mention the effects of not using the helper, nor does he mention the implications on the validation. I've commented on that thread as well, before posting this though.

Comment: you are setting RouteValueDictionary, where you need to set htmlAttributs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492719.aspx) method with single parameter is used to generate a relative path from  routedata that is provided within parameter variable. Which means, that you are setting URI parameter with name `action` and giving it and value `http://absolute.com`, therefor value is going to be encoded.

What you want to use is [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470539.aspx) where it asks you for htmlAttributes.

This **will not encode** value for action attribute:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
     null, null, FormMethod.Post,
     new {@action="http://absolute.com/submit/example"}
)){}
// the result is:
<form action="http://absolute.com/submit/example" method="post"> 
</form>
```

***UPDATE:** method show below will not utilize JavaScript client-side validation.*

since, you don't really need the helper to figure out the path of the form. You can use the html and set action of the form manually.

Validation will still work, if you are using helpers for the input fields.

```
<form action="http://absolute.com/submit/example" method="post">    
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Example)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Example, "*")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Example, 8, 60, null)
</form>
```

Comment: Clientside validation does not work if you do not use the helper TO CREATE THE FORM . I know this for sure, you can try it out yourself. I looked at MVC3's source and found that the helper was creating some FormContext objects when you say BeginForm() - This maybe what we are missing when we handwrite the form tag.

Comment: yeah, it is not possible to leverage client side validation if <form> element is created manually.

Answer (score 0):

One way is..we can use RedirectResult("http://absolute.com"); in the controller action method.

If you are redirecting from your controller (or action filter, etc.) you can use the RedirectResult as your ActionResult type.

Comment: Posting to my action, then redirecting it will cause a get request to `"http://absolute.com"`, whereas I want a post request. Plus how will I transfer all the posted values, posted to my action, to `http://absolute.com"`?