# redirect from one action to post method of some different action with model value as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I got the value of text box from view to one of my action in the controller. Now I need to send this value to post method of some other action which takes model values as its parameter.
The action where I got the value from controller :

```
public ActionResult Track(string txtEmployeeNo)
    {
        ReporteesInboxModel objTrackRequestModel1 = new ReporteesInboxModel();
        objTrackRequestModel1.strempno = txtEmployeeNo;

        return RedirectToAction("TrackRequest", new { objTrackRequestModel = objTrackRequestModel1, ActionStatus = "" });
    }
```

I need to redirect it to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TrackRequest(ReporteesInboxModel objTrackRequestModel, string ActionStatus)
{
......
}
```

but the line :

```
return RedirectToAction("TrackRequest", new { objTrackRequestModel = objTrackRequestModel1, ActionStatus = "" });
```

redirects me to the GET method and not the post method.

Comment: `RedirectToAction()` is always to a GET

Comment: Why you need to do that? Just post it from client side.

Comment: Actually, you can't redirect using post method. Please refer to these questions. [question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286382/how-to-redirect-asp-net-mvc-with-a-post)
[question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643414/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-parameters-to-post-action) they are also trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` only points to method using `HttpGet`, hence you need a POST request either using form submit or AJAX call. Returning view to perform POST request is more preferred than redirection.