# How to post a form to an url in asp .net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, post

Im new to asp .net mvc3. I have a requirement that i  post a form to a url say "www.abc.com/asa" . I have added a submit button to my application. But every time i click the button, form gets submitted to corresponding controller. How can i post to my required url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965103/html-beginform-with-an-absolute-url

Comment: I think your best bet here would be to either hijack the form post via jquery as you are always going to have to route via the controller by convention OR you nullify the actionname and controller parameters.  Manatherin's comment above gives the required pointers to this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in mvc we follow below convention:

```
[httpGet] //default not to mention
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Todo code here
}

[httpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
   // Form submit here, all form data available here
}
```

But in your case you may write following in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", "FormMethod", "HTML Attributes"))
{
   // Here Controller: it defines whose actionmethod need to be called when form get submitted.
}
```

EX:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@action="http://www.abc.com/asa"})
{
}
```

Comment: darshin -re-read the OP. he explicitly mentions that he DOESN'T want to make a traditional call to the controller. I haven't marked you down, coz it's a genuine error on your part, but I'm certain you will be unless you edit your answer

Comment: @jimtollan: have edited the answer, do comment if it has bug. And thanks for driving my attention.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest using a standard html `<form />` tag with the appropriate url in action parameter.

BeginForm helpers always take action and controller as parameters - you can't use the standard ones.

If you want you can define your own helper too. I would do that if this is a bigger application and you'll be using this multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="www.abc.com/asa" method="POST">
   <legend>
     Foo
   </legend>
   <fieldset>
      <p>Fields</p>
   </fieldset>

   <input type="submit" name"submitForm" value="submitForm" />
</form>
```