# How To Make Equiv POST with MVC5 as webforms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm posting data to Authorize.net and have webforms code that looks like the following:

```
<form id="simForm" runat="server" method='post' action='https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'>
    <input id="HiddenValue" type="hidden" value="Initial Value" runat="server" />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_login' id='x_login' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_amount' id='x_amount' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_description' id='x_description' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_invoice_num' id='x_invoice_num' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_fp_sequence' id='x_fp_sequence' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_fp_timestamp' id='x_fp_timestamp' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_fp_hash' id='x_fp_hash' />
    <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_test_request' id='x_test_request' />
    <input type='hidden' name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />
    <input type='submit' runat="server" id='buttonLabel' />
</form>
```

I'm wanting to do the same thing with controllers and razor in asp.net MVC5.  I'm trying something along the lines of waht I have below but don't quite get it.  especially the part about the action=https://test.au..

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "AuthNet",FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.Hidden("x_login", "mylogincred")

        <button type="submit">Process</button>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `action` part see here: [Html.BeginForm() with an absolute URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965103/html-beginform-with-an-absolute-url)

Just have to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload of [BeginForm()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Use this overload as follows with `actionName` and `controllerName` as `null`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { action = "https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" })){ }
```

Also, if you have a strongly-typed view, you can pass a View Model to your view and use `Html.HiddenFor()` helper to populate the hidden input elements.

Comment: is the actionname the absolute URL?  then does it ignore the controller with that overload?

Comment: Updated answer with example.